# Why do I get a JavaScript error after logging into a website with Watir-Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a lovely error that comes from Selenium Webdirver I can't seem to get past and was hoping someone here might have some advice.

**Overview**

I'm using Ruby and Watir-Webdriver to drive a Firefox browser to systematically check for updates on MSDN, then perform some automated tasks if need be.  I'm getting a JS error from webdriver after I log into the website, and my browser instance becomes unusable.  Always happens at the same spot, never fail for the past few days I've been trying it.

**Information**

Windows XP Pro SP3

ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]

selenium-webdriver (2.19.0)

watir-webdriver (0.5.3)

**Error Message**

```
irb(main):020:0> browser.goto "http://www.google.com"
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: '[JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file:"file:///C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/webdriver-rb-profilecopy20120220-520-1q19c5x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js" line: 10092}]' when calling method: [nsICommandProcessor::execute]
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:64:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:590:in `raw_execute'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:568:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:14:in `to'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.5.3/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:61:in `goto'
    from (irb):20
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

**My Abbreviated Ruby Code**

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'win32ole'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => "default"
browser.goto "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/"

ai = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
browser.goto browser.link(:text => "Sign in").attribute_value('href')

browser.text_field(:name, "login").clear
browser.text_field(:name, "login").set "USERNAME"
browser.text_field(:name, "passwd").clear
browser.text_field(:name, "passwd").set "PASSWORD"

browser.button(:name, "LOGIN_BUTTON").click

# Secure to Non Secure page brings up a dialog, just send enter to dismiss
ai.winWaitActive("Security Warning", "", 15)
ai.Send("{ENTER}")
```

After this point if I try to do anything with the browser instance, go to a new URL, check the status, etc., I get the same error message from Selenium Webdriver.

> browser.status -> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: '[JavaScript Error: "a is null" ...
>
> browser.url -> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: '[JavaScript Error: "a is null" ...
>
> browser.goto "http://www.google.com" -> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: '[JavaScript Error: "a is null" ...

I searched online for something similar but so far I can't find a good handle on why this is happening.  I think, think, it has something to do with being redirected from the login.live.com secure page, back to the main MSDN page, but this in only a guess.  I can use Webdriver with Ruby with no problems doing any other set of tasks and have been doing so all day today.  The only time I can reproduce, is after logging into MSDN.

This computer was just updated with all patches and upgrades so something is not playing nicely now, but I just don't understand what exactly it could be. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I got the same error message several times a few days ago after I dismiss the "are you sure you want to leave this page" popup.

Comment: do you have the same issue if you use a different browser, or use watir to drive IE?   I wonder if there is some sort of anti-scripting code on that page (you might understand why that might be considered a good thing by MS since they might not want someone to wrap their page and fake someone into thinking they were installing an update when it's really something else...

Comment: I wonder if maybe firefox is doing something under the covers at that point similar to IE when the security context is getting switched around a lot.   Potentially maybe you want to try using the window switching code to see if you can reconnect to the browser window?

Comment: I tried this with IE and it does work correctly.  Unfortunate since I use Firefox and like to switch between Windows and OS X.  Also, from what I've read online, attach is not supported in Watir-Webdriver [link](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/232df221602d4cfb?pli=1) but that sounds like a great idea to try.  I'll keep on it and see if I can find something similar that might work, thanks.